# Can't use instance of graph management

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I connect to gremlin-server from gremlin console with this configuration:

connect_config.yaml

```
hosts: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
port: XXXX
serializer: {
  className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0,
  config: {
    serializeResultToString: true,
    ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry]
  }
}
```

when i run method graph.openManagement() it will ok

```
gremlin> graph.openManagement()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@392e7533
```

but when i try save reference to management object and use it i get error:

```
gremlin> m=graph.openManagement()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@326fbc0a
gremlin> m.commit()
No such property: m for class: Script8
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: No such property: m for class: Script8
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:188)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:481)
```

What is this error, and what i must do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you are not using a [session](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#console-sessions) in Gremlin Console:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server connect_config session
```